# How to add navigation case for Virtual directory

Tags: java, jsf-2, navigation, ejb-3.0

In my app, I have a [Virtual directory](http://www.marceble.com/2009/07/virtual-directories-in-glassfish/) to store files for downloading. I wanted to create a `<h:button>` with `outcome="<virtual-directory-URL>/<file-name>"` to download the file. However, I always ran into the error `Navigation case not resolved`.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me how I should tackle this problem.

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution: a combination of `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:button>` would do. It should be something like this:

```
<h:outputLink value="<virtual-directory-URL>/<file-name>">
    <h:button value="Download" />
</h:outputLink>
```